# Where to save nginx rewrite rules?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I am thinking about replacing apache webserver with nginx but some websites use .htaccess file and I want to ask... it is possible to declare rewrite rules inside website directory and not in server configuration? How? Is there any file like .htaccess?  Sorry for questions but nginx is new for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does the nginx documentation say about this issue?

Comment: Read this http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess

Comment: Thanks but I already read this. But I have few users on my server and I want to know how can I allow modifying rewrite rules for my users...

Comment: @guest Look, if the documentation for a server says "don't do that", the answer to "how do I do that?" is probably "you don't". If you need Apache's features, stick to Apache.

Comment: There is no .htaccess in nginx because it reads config once at start while Apache reads .htaccess files on every request. So it's impossible to have nginx act like apache in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Why would you even want to? nginx is built for speed, this would just slow it down. You can do includes if you want to keep your config cleaner though. Something like this would work

```
server {
include includes/rewrites.conf;
...
}
```

Then just have a directory called includes and store the rewrites there.